# image editor in wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, image-editor

my wordpress image editor is not showing image to crop. It shows the image in media library but when i click to edit image the image is not showing. The Image url it is showing is

wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=0b98ac9553&postid=415&rand=29813

Comment: Unless you want to provide a username & password for your site,which you probably should not do, the link you included isn't of any use.

Comment: but why the image editor is not showing the picture

Answer (score 4):

If you still need the answer, this is because your server does not have the PHP5-GD library installed. You can install using putty like this:

sudo apt-get install php5-gd

If your server is managed, ask your hosting company to install it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

- Removed all blank lines and whitespaces in /wp-content/themes/name/functions.php + the including files.
- Removed all blank lines and whitespaces in /wp-config.php
- Check that php5-gd is installed.
- Permissions changed to 777 for testing /wp-content/upload/ + sub folders
- Removed closing ?> tags in /wp-content/themes/name/functions.php + the including files.
- Turned off all plugins.
- Rename your and changed to default theme.

Answer (score 0):

So we were having the same issue you asked above and eventually found the issue.  When you install PHP on a windows machine the PHP.ini file initially points uploads, errors, etc to the Windows/Temp file.  In order for things to function correctly you have to change the IIS_IUSR security level to have at minimum Read/Write on that folder, we changed it to full control.  For whatever quirky reason WordPress sets the file permission from the folder it originates from (i.e. the Windows/Temp folder) when it dumps it into the WP-Content/Uploads folder.  Another quirky thing is on Window's servers anytime you shut down and restart the server all the folders in the Windows folder revert back to default security settings, meaning each time the server shuts down you have to go back to that Temp folder and reassign permissions for IIS_IUSR